# Debug.WriteLine locks

Tags: c#, multithreading

My program frequently stops with a deadlock. When I do a break-all and look at the threads I see that three threads are stuck in our logging function:

```
public class Logging
{
    public static void WriteClientLog(LogLevel logLevel, string message)
    {
      #if DEBUG
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), message)); //LOCK
      #endif
      //...Log4net logging
    }
}
```

If I let the program continue the threads are still stuck on that line.

I can't see where this can lock. The debug class, string class & datetime class seem to be thread safe.

The error goes away when I remove the `#if DEBUG System... #endif` code but I'm curious why this behavior happens.

Thread one:

```
public void CleanCache()
{
    Logging.WriteClientLog(LogLevel.Debug, "Start clean cache.");//Stuck
}
```

Thread two:

```
private void AliveThread()
{
    Logging.WriteClientLog(LogLevel.Debug, "Check connection");//Stuck
}
```

Comment: So if you just remove the if debug and endif messages, but leave the write line in the method, it works fine?

Comment: Do you have custom trace listeners configured?

Comment: i've run into a similar issue...which ended in me switching to using MS's enterprise libary logging.  made for far less headaches.

Comment: No custom trace listeners, I only see the DefaultraceListener in the Debug list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Debug.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx) writes logging messages to the attached Trace Listeners attached to the [Listeners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.listeners.aspx) collection.

One of your trace listeners must have a lock internally which is causing a deadlock.  Check your listener code, as it's most likely the culprit.